# Group dates by considering look ahead days

Tags: sql-server, group-by, window-functions

I am using SQL Server 2017. I have a table Requests, to make things simple, there's only one column RequestDate. For example,

```
RquestDate
4/11
4/12
4/13
4/16
4/18
```

I need to group by RequestDate by considering look ahead days. If look ahead day is 0, the result should be the same as raw table.

If look ahead day is 1, it means when I look at 4/11, I need to check if 4/12 exists, if so, group 4/12 into 4/11.
The result is:

```
4/11 --it groups 4/12
4/13
4/16
4/18
```

If look ahead day is 2, when looking at 4/11, it groups 4/12, 4/13 into it.
The result is:

```
4/11 -- group 4/12 and 4/13.
4/16 -- group 4/18
```

So this problem is different from the typical gap and island problem. Because when group dates, there could be gap there, e.g, when look ahead day is 2, 4/16 groups 4/17 and 4/18.

I tried some ways but can't find a decent solution.

Comment: Please show us what you tried. And clarify, is the number of look ahead days fixed for a given run of the query? And I encourage you to add some sample data using DDL+DML as this makes it easier for people to have a play and potentially answer.

Comment: And even though 13 is only 1 more than 12, it definitely starts a new group and is not grouped with 11 & 12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive common table expression could work.

1. Select start request date using a `min()` function.
2. Use that same date as the grouping start date.

*Step 1 and 2 make up the recursion anchor / start row.*

3. Recursively go looking for the next request date. This date is higher than the previous date (`r.RequestDate > c.RequestDate`) and does not have another row
   that follow the same criteria before it (`not exists ... r2.RequestDate < r.RequestDate`).
4. If the current request date (from step 3) falls within the look ahead interval length, then maintain the grouping start date (`then c.RequestGroupDate`), otherwise start a new group on the current request date (`else r.RequestDate`).

*Step 3 and 4 make up the recursive part of the CTE.*

5. After the recursion every request date as a corresponding request grouping date. The `group by r.RequestGroupDate` clause reduces the result output to the distinct values.

**Sample data**

```
create table Requests
(
  RequestDate date
);

insert into Requests (RequestDate) values
('2021-04-11'),
('2021-04-12'),
('2021-04-13'),
('2021-04-16'),
('2021-04-18');
```

**Solution**

```
declare @lookAhead int = 1; -- look ahead days parameter

with rcte as
(
  select min(r.RequestDate) as RequestDate,
         min(r.RequestDate) as RequestGroupDate
  from Requests r
union all
  select r.RequestDate,
         case
           when datediff(day, c.RequestGroupDate, r.RequestDate) <= @lookAhead
           then c.RequestGroupDate
           else r.RequestDate
         end
  from rcte c
  join Requests r
    on r.RequestDate > c.RequestDate
  where not exists ( select 'x'
                     from Requests r2
                     where r2.RequestDate > c.RequestDate
                       and r2.RequestDate < r.RequestDate )
)
select r.RequestGroupDate
from rcte r
group by r.RequestGroupDate;
```

**Result**

For `@lookAhead = 1`:

```
RequestGroupDate
----------------
2021-04-11
2021-04-13
2021-04-16
2021-04-18
```

For `@lookahead = 2`:

```
RequestGroupDate
----------------
2021-04-11
2021-04-16
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=edf7f279154446497b29614cdf0df1ea) to see things in action.

Comment: Could you document the logic of how that works. Its a great solution, but tricky to make sense of how it works.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the "where not exists" clause forces CTE processes the table row by row.

It is like a cursor moving from oldest RequestDate to newest RequestDate. For each move, it carries the previous RequestGroupDate and determines whether the current row belongs to previous ReuqestGroupDate. If not, it uses its own RequestDate as the new RequestGroupDate.

My only concern is max depth of SQL CTE Recursive is 32767. Does it mean it can't handle a table with more than 32767 rows. I will test it. @Sander.

Comment: @DaleK, I have added a solution description with steps.

Comment: @FrankZhang, in case the recursion limit would pose a problem, then please ask another question and explain why this solution is not working for you.

Comment: @Sander thanks for that - still trying to get my head around step 3 :) it requires some mind bending.